# iPhone locks itself while I’m speaking on it

Tags: iphone, screen-lock, call

Whenever I’m on a phone call with my iPhone 6S, the phone locks itself. The actual call continues normally, but if I want to access the screen, including to end the call, I have to unlock the phone using Touch ID or by entering my passcode.

This has been happening for a few months now. Does anyone know how to fix this in settings?